# Algorithm to rotate values in a predefined manner

Tags: encryption, key-rotation

I will start with an example. Some beacon like estimote Beacons use something called [secure ID](https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/201371053-Are-Estimote-Beacons-secure-How-does-Secure-UUID-work-). The ID transmitted by the beacon change every 10 minutes autonomously without contacting the server. When the new ID are sent to the server, this one can identify the beacon generating the ID.

This is exactly what I want to do. I have a raspberry pi acting like a beacon and transmitting an ID. I want to share the original ID and maybe a key with the server. Then using this key, I want to crypt or change the original ID value every few minutes and I want the server to be able to identify the original ID.

Is there any function that allow that ? I have almost no knowledge about cryptography, is there any good book/article that can help me understand what I should do ?

Comment: What security property are you after? ​ (Specifically, why doesn't "increase the ID by 1" work?) ​ ​ ​ ​